# Retrieving amazon order history programmatically using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, web-scraping

I want to log into my amazon account and retrieve purchase history programmatically in java.

I did a lot of research and came across screen scraping. Is this the only way or does amazon provide apis for logging in and retrieving purchase history?

Also researched about AWS but its too confusing. There are lot of APIs and I'm not able to figure out which one to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't look like Amazon provides an API to specifically do what you need, however I came across [this thread.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5801/amazon-web-service-to-get-purchase-data) You may have already seen it.

Comment: thanks for your response. Amazon doesn't provide API for importing purchase history. The only solution I can see is screen scraping.

Comment: Any idea if this violates ToS or anything?

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, and didn't find a public Amazon API for retrieving purchase history.

So, I built a Chrome Extension to solve it. The repo is [open-source and available here](https://github.com/ElishaKay/udemy-fullstack-chrome-extension).

I also built a Udemy Course which essentially reviews the codebase: https://www.udemy.com/course/build-a-full-stack-chrome-extension-with-nodejs-and-mongdb

Here's the Chrome Extension: [Amazon Scraper King](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/my-amazon-history/epmjnoajehdombhjonaoifmhbkkflnli)

I also built a web app which enables you to take your Amazon History and [create a Social Shopping Profile](https://myamazonhistory.com).

Comment: hi @ElishaKramer your github repo link is invalid, do you still have that code or its being removed?

Comment: Hi @user42012, my bad - I fixed the link now and yes, it's still open source, plus there's even a Udemy Course on it:

https://www.udemy.com/course/build-a-full-stack-chrome-extension-with-nodejs-and-mongdb

Comment: Thank you Elisha, appreciate your help and detailed information.